# WIX Burn MSI Properties Being Overridden

Tags: wix, windows-installer, burn

I am building a WIX bootstrapper to call some pre-existing MSIs we have. The overall install is working and I can see in the log that I am able to successfully pass parameters from the BS to the MSI. However, I see in the log file that the parameters are then being overridden.

The MSI was created using the Visual Studio deployment project templates. In the UI, we pre-populate some of the entry fields with default values. So basically those defaults are overriding the values I am passing in from the bootstrapper. Can this be avoided?

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you are setting the default values, but in your situation I would use a WiX SetProperty element to set the default values with a condition of Not PROPERTYNAME so that it won't be set if it's already set.